# Get rid of extra fold dashes when using Vim folding

Tags: vimrc, folding

I am using the script from [here](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_dotfiles/blob/a1a106081884647922395fe4512aa8fcc887d64c/plugin/CustomFoldText.vim), and it seems setting the  g:custom_foldtext_max_width variable cannot get rid of the extra "--" symbols in the end of the folded lines.

Is there any way to make the folded line not go beyond 80 characters ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can

```
set fillchars=fold:\
```

See [`:h fillchars`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'fillchars').

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works for removing the ending dashes. But is it possible to also remove the extra background highlighting after 80 chars ?

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible. :\

Comment: Notice the space after \